# Ansible: Add integer value to a list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to add integer value to a list in Ansible (to create a new variable).
For example, I have the following variable:

```
list: 
   - 80
   - 81
   - 82
```

I would like to do something like:

```
list2: "{{ list + 100 }}"
```

to get:

```
list2: 
   - 180
   - 181
   - 182
```

I have tried with

```
list2: "{{ list|int+100 }}"
```

or

```
list2: "{{ list+100|int }}"
```

but without success so far. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write a custom filter plugin or use looped set_fact:

```
- set_fact:
    list2: "{{ list2 | default([]) + [item+100] }}"
  with_items: "{{ list1 }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I'm trying to do this in a variable file. I understand that there is not simple way to do it. 
So I have used :

```
list2: "[ {% for port in list1 %}{{ port+100 }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %} ]"
```